# Proxmox VM Very Slow Performance

Tags: linux, virtualization, proxmox

I'm new in proxmox, I just installing proxmox on my pc core i5/3.5ghz/15gb/500gb sata 
And I installing windows 7 with 4gb vram and 4 core proc.
But when I trying to console it the response is very slow.
What's wrong with this machine?
And also I try to install ubuntu server linux as a VM also very slow performance.
Any one have solution to fix this problem I will very appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

(This question seems to be off-topic for the ServerFault forum, but here goes...)

The Proxmox VE console will feel sluggish, yes. If you connect to the machine over RDP, does it feel better?

If you set the VM to perform server-like tasks rather than to act like a desktop OS, is its objective performance underwhelming compared to running a similar load on another hypervisor?

Remember that Proxmox is tuned for server use out of the box. If you want to run a desktop OS on it with anything resembling a desktop experience, I suggest reading up on tuning KVM on Debian.

Comment: kvm perform a bit better for Desktop

Comment: @djdomi: Proxmox uses KVM for virtualization, but is intended for server use and tuned for that.

Comment: your right i was interrupted in my sentence i wanted to agree to you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have adequate RAM available for the VM (under `Hardware` settings for the VM). Also, be sure your guest is using the `virtio` drivers as well as a `virtio` enabled storage device. If you can put the VM on an SSD disk, performance will improve drastically. SATA disks, no matter how many, are horrible for VM performance. The IOPS just aren't there when you start running multiple VMs. Use a utility like `sysstat` to check on swap performance `sar -B` as well as `iostat -xdp 1` to monitor disk usage. if the `%util` column is constantly above 50% your having disk IO issues.